# SQL selecting from 3 tables with the same column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables with the following structure:

```
sequence
cli
datetime
company
```

the tables are `orders_broadband` `orders_lines` and `orders_porting`

i want to display results from all three tables within the same result set.

i have tried running the query:

```
SELECT orders_broadband.*, orders_lines.*, orders_porting.* from orders_broadband, orders_lines, orders_porting
```

but i dont think i have the query correct

Comment: I'm not I uderstand. all the tables are the same structure and you want to see all the records in one table? if it's the case, you should use UNIOIN operation

Comment: @user5224389 `UNION` as opposed to `UNIOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
select sequence, cli, datetime, company from orders_broadband
union all
select sequence, cli, datetime, company from orders_lines
union all
select sequence, cli, datetime, company from orders_porting
```

That will combine data from all 3 tables.

Edited by adding column names explicity (similar to what xQbert mentioned in the comments section)

**Show tablename**

```
select sequence, cli, datetime, company, 'Tablename1' as tbl from orders_broadband where status = 'New' 
UNION ALL 
select sequence, cli, datetime, company, 'Tablename2' as tbl from orders_lines where status = 'New' 
UNION ALL 
select sequence, cli, datetime, company, 'Tablename3' as tbl from orders_porting where status = 'New'
```

Change 'Tablename1' and others to whatever you feel comfortable.

**What if I want to add an additional column from orders_broadband?**

```
select '' as telephone_number, sequence, cli, datetime, company, 'Tablename1' as tbl from orders_broadband where status = 'New' 
UNION ALL 
select '' as telephone_number, sequence, cli, datetime, company, 'Tablename2' as tbl from orders_lines where status = 'New' 
UNION ALL 
select telephone_number, sequence, cli, datetime, company, 'Tablename3' as tbl from orders_porting where status = 'New'
```

Comment: i am getting this message back now ` #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns` - sorry i should have mentioned that there are some extra columns in each table

Comment: Then change * in each of the queries to `sequence, cli, datetime, company`  Assuming you want to RETAIN duplicates.  If you want to remove duplicates use `UNION` instead of `union all`  UNION executes a distinct on the results, eliminating repeated rows at a cost of some performance.

Comment: @charlie Answer has been edited by adding explicit column names. Also, thank you xQbert for adding relevant details.

Comment: ok - i have this query: `select sequence, cli, datetime, company from orders_broadband as `TableName` where status = 'New' UNION ALL select sequence, cli, datetime, company from orders_lines as `TableName` where status = 'New' UNION ALL select sequence, telephone_number, datetime, company from orders_porting as `TableName` where status = 'New'` which works perfectly. however, the `TableName` is not showing in the results. how can i get the table name to display too?

Comment: @charlie - added information to help you with the latest comment

Comment: if i select a different amount of columns on each query i get an error

Comment: @charlie - that is by design of nearly any modern database. The # of columns, their position and datatypes should be similar. You are free to create dummy fields to keep unioned queries consistent like this: `select custid, 'dummy' as custname, age from table1 UNION ALL select custid, custname, 0 as age from table2`